# Github Action Mkdocs with Aws-Cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, github-pages, aws-cdk

i am getting a terminal error saying:

`remote: Write access to repository not granted. fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/@username/cdk-github/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

I created my project using AWS CDK, Gitgub action then adding Material for MkDOcs for documentation.
The first job(aws_cdk) ran with no issues but I keep getting error in this part of the code "mkdocs gh-deploy --force".
Below is my code:

```
name: Deploy AWS CDK

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  #pull_request:
    #branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  #workflow_dispatch:

env:
    AWS_REGION : eu-central-1

# Permission can be added at job level or workflow level    
permissions:
    id-token: write 
    contents: read 

jobs:
  aws_cdk:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::@acctid:role/GitHubAction-AssumeRoleWithAction
          role-session-name: samplerolesession

      - name: install npm
        run: 'sudo apt update -y && sudo apt install nodejs npm -y'

      - name: Install AWS CDK
        run: 'sudo npm install -g aws-cdk' 

      - name: Install Requirements 
        run: 'pip3 install -r requirements.txt'
        working-directory: .

      - name: CDK Synth
        run: cdk synth
        working-directory: .
              
      - name: CDK bootstrap
        run: cdk bootstrap
        working-directory: .

      - name: CDK Deploy
        run: cdk deploy --require-approval never --verbose
        working-directory: .
        
      - name: CDK Destroy
        run: cdk destroy --force
        working-directory: .

  docs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: aws_cdk
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Checkout python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
      - run: pip install mkdocs-material
      - run: mkdocs gh-deploy --force
```

Please, how can I get past this?

I have enabled workflow Read and write permissions in the repository settings and also created Personal access token enabling content read and write access for repositories premission in the Developer settings but this still doesn't work.